# Android приложение работающее на excel

Tags: android, excel

Нужно обернуть excel книгу в оболочку android приложения. В какой папке сохранить ключевой файл , чтоб можно было с ним полноценно работать, а не только читать (как из assets например)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ни в какой, придется сохранять на внутренний/внешний диск.

Comment: вы принципе не сможете никак изменять файлы, которые лежат в исходном проекте. ваш лучше положить файл в assets, потом скопировать его во внутреннюю память телефона и работать с ним.

Comment: @Wlad подскажите ссылку на хорошую инструкцию?  как это сделать? Я сохранял excel в папке files. Но он оттуда не читается ( ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: 1) это уже другой вопрос про "запись / чтение". 2) прикладывайте код. а по сабжу: гуглите в сторону "android assets запись".